# android layout xml properties and positioning...

Tags: android, android-layout, view, properties

I have a problem and I have tried googling and searching in other ways but I dont know what to search for...

my layout is like this:

```
 _______________________________________________________
|           |        |                                  |
|           |        |                                  |  
|  content  | button |                                  |
|           |        |                                  | 
|___________|________|__________________________________|
```

but if I add a little more it will look like this:

```
 _______________________________________________________
|                         |        |                    |
|                         |        |                    |  
|  content                | button |                    |
|                         |        |                    | 
|_________________________|________|____________________|
```

but when the content is bigger than the wrapper I want to make the content scrollable but show the button in the end of the wrapper like this:

```
 _______________________________________________________
|                                              |        |  
|                                              |        |  
|   scrollable content                         | button |  
|                                              |        |  
|______________________________________________|________|
```

So it wont matter how much content there is, the button will always be visible and the content will be horizontaly scollable :)

my code right now is something like this but I dont know what to do so I can get it like I want:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" >


        <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
            </LinearLayout>             
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" >
            <ImageButton 
                android:layout_width="@dimen/TopBarHeight"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put your linearlayout with your button in your horizontalscrollview?

Comment: If I do that the button vill disapear when the scrollview is full

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a top LinearLayout with a total layout weight of 4 and horizontal.
Then create another linear layout for content, give that one a weight of 3 and put a scrollview inside. Create another linearlayout with weight of 1 and add the button to that layout.

Alternatively use a relativelayout. Then you can specify that the scrollview aligns to the parent left, and to the right of the button. And the button aligns to the parent right and to the right of the scrollview.

EDITED: Here is an example of RelativeLayout that will do what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have added a RelativeLayout to my answer that will do exactly what you want I believe.

Comment: The button is always on the right edge of the screen for some reason... like if the scrollview had fill_parent...

Comment: OK. If you don't want that to happen. Change the Button layout properties: Remove "android:layout_alignParentRight=true" add in "android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView1". All the layout options are at the bottom of the properties view. Relative layout is very powerful and worth spending time to learn :)

Comment: I added some code in the end of your answer.. I tried that but with no success... :( what am I doing wrong? everyting is right but when the content is to much the button disapears.. I want it to never go outside the screen...

Comment: How about surrounding the Button in a linear layout. That has alignParentRight="true" ans layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView1" and have the width set to fill_parent. That might work.

Comment: added code again... it works at a beginning but when the scrollviews content gets wide the button disapears...

Comment: My only other suggestion would be to try and use the layout maxWidth. But this will pose problems as the width will change per device (you should be able to get this information though), also when the screen rotates this would need to change the maxWidth again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <ImageButton android:layout_width="@dimen/TopBarHeight" android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" android:src="@drawable/icon"></ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but whit that code the button will always be at the right edge...

Answer (score 0):

User Layout Gravity for HorizontalScrollView and LinearLayout containing ImageButton as below.

changes are as per below points

1. Add android:layout_weight="1" in HorizontalScrollView
2. Add    android:layout_width="fill_parent" in HorizontalScrollView
3. Add    android:layout_weight="4" in second Linearlayout containing    Imagebutton

   ```
           <HorizontalScrollView 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" 
   android:layout_weight="1">
               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" >
                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                       android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                       android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                       android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                       android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                       android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="@dimen/TabMaxWidth"
                       android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" />
               </LinearLayout>             
           </HorizontalScrollView>
           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight" 
   android:layout_weight="4">
               <ImageButton 
                   android:layout_width="@dimen/TopBarHeight"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/TopBarHeight"/>
           </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
   ```